# NSTimer: floating point value can not be converted to UInt8 because it is greater than UInt8.max

Tags: xcode, swift, timer, int, nstimer

My code returns the error: fatal error: floating point value can not be converted to UInt8 because it is greater than UInt8.max. The code is being called when a button is pressed (in a different swift file) but I know that the problem wasn't with calling the function so I didn't include it.

code:

```
//starts the timer
func startTimer(sender: AnyObject)
{
if !timer.valid
{
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: sender, selector:     Selector(updateTime()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    //disp = timerDisplay
}
}

//function that configures the timer
func updateTime()
{
var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

//find the difference between the current time and the start time
var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

//calculate the seconds in elapsed time
let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)

///find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed
let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 10)

//add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants
//let strMinutes = minutes > 9 ? String(minutes):"0" + String(minutes)
let strSeconds = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds):"0" + String(seconds)
let strFraction = fraction > 9 ? String(fraction):"0" + String(fraction)

//display the time left to a string
timerDisplay = "\(strSeconds):\(strFraction)"
}

func stopTimer()
{
timer.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @recursive I would like to know how to solve the error and get the code working properly.

Comment: I see.  The problem is basically explained in the title of the post.  May I ask why you are using `UInt8`?  It can only store values up to 255, so that is going to be limiting.

Comment: That is what the tutorial said to do. I tried UInt16, and got the same error. When trying Uint32 or Uint64 the app crashes and gives no error

Comment: The error message specifically refers to `UInt8`, so if you tried `UInt16` and got the same error, you're probably not executing the code that you think you are.

Answer (score 3):

I would take a different approach at it since you will need to represent NSTimeInterval many times, so you should consider adding a read-only computed property as an extension to your project to return a string representation of it as follow:

```
extension NSTimeInterval {
    var time:String {
        return String(format:"%d:%02d:%02d.%02d", Int(self/3600.0), Int((self/60.0) % 60), Int((self) % 60 ), Int(self*100 % 100 ))
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //declarations
    @IBOutlet weak var tappedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

    var startTime = NSTimeInterval()
    var timer = NSTimer()

    //starts the timer
    func startTimer(sender: AnyObject) {
        if !timer.valid {
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: sender, selector: "updateTime", userInfo: nil, repeats:true)
            startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        }
    }
    // calculates the elapsed time in seconds (Double = NSTimeInterval).extension NStimeInterval
    func updateTime() {
        //find the difference between the current time and the start time and return a string out of it
                // updates the text field
        timerLabel.text = (NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - startTime).time
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Where do I put let myTimeStringDescription = elapsedTime.time?

Comment: You can put the extensions in a separate swift source file and use the .time extension anywhere with any NSTimeInterval object it will return a String out of it.

Comment: yourTextOutlet.text = elapsedTime.time

Comment: Now I am getting the following error: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Are you coding for iOS or OSX ?

Comment: I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: If you post a link to your project I can take a look at your code and fix it for you

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate this. link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/746qomg3nqlgeoc/Finger%20Speed.zip?dl=0

Comment: You have to learn where to put your functions. If they will update the UILabel they can't be in a different file.

Comment: Your code is so confusing I couldn't test. :) Give it a try and continue it from there.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Do you have any tips for me to make my code less confusing?

Comment: Also, would you mind telling me what the problem was?

Comment: If it works and solved your problem you should accept the answer selecting the green checkmark

Comment: You are welcome. The problem: You were placing your functions at the wrong place.

Comment: @LeoDabus -- good answer my bro,I learned the new one in swift,

Comment: I learned like 3 different things from this one answer.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

`UNint8` can only store values up to 64k (64*1024). If the bucket is full you can't stuff any more into it. Use a larger bucket `Int` will cope with zillions of digits.